# How to show information given by the servlet in the browser instead of the console?

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have made a servlet in Eclipse and am running it on Tomcat server. The servlet is getting some data from an API using username and apitoken.

I have made an file namely index.jsp. It has a navigation bar and few buttons.

Now I am calling the servlet when clicking one button in my index.jsp. On click of the button- the console displays the JSON data and nothing on the browser running on Tomcat.

Ideally I want the browser to display the JSON data on the browser. Would anybody be able to help me with some coding?

This is my button calling the server in index.jsp:

```js
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
      function callServlet() {
          document.forms[0].action = "testing";
          document.forms[0].submit();
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
..
.
.
<form id="WhatsNewFormID" name="WhatsNewForm" method="post">
  <div id="WhatsNewBtn"><input id="btn" type="submit" value="Hello World" style="float:right" class="w3-button w3-bar-item" onclick="callServlet();" /></div>
  </form>
  .
  .
  
 </body>
```

And this is a part of my servlet:

```
String theUrl="TheURLForTheApiZZZ";
          URL url = new URL(theUrl);
```

// create a urlconnection object
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

```
 String userpass = "usernameXXX" + ":" + "apitokenYYY; 
              String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
              urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
             
          
          // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
          BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

          String line;

          // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
          while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
          {
            content.append(line + "\n");
          }
          bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
     output= content.toString();
     System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed writing the content to the response object (`HttpServletResponse response`) which is responsible for sending the content to the browser. Just before the line, `System.out.println(output)`, put the following code in your servlet:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write(output);
```

If you do not want to display the content on the console, simply remove the line, `System.out.println(output);`

Comment: Thank you. By just adding your code, it says "response" is not created. 
So then I create "response" object by writing - HttpServletResponse response; before the 4 lines you mentioned. 

It now says response is not initialized and asks me to initialize it to null. Once I initialize it to null - it gives me a "java.lang.NullPointerException".Then, I simply extend my class by writing -> public class Testing extends HttpServletResponseWrapper implements Servlet { ....} . 
After this it automatically makes a constructor -> 
public Testing(HttpServletResponse response) {
 super(response); 
}

Comment: ...(contd.)   Even now after this, it gives me a NullPointerException. Would you be able to see what the problem could be?

Comment: Just to add - I am doing all of this in the public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1) throws ServletException, IOException {           ..................      }

Comment: @stuti - do all these inside `public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {...}`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. It did not work with the exact code. What I eventually did was returned the response from the servlet and appended the JSON to my container in JS and CSS. But, I think the doGet would have worked as well! Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Yes, `doGet` will definitely work. Maybe you can try it later for some other use case.